# What is the optimal file output buffer size?

Tags: c++, c, io, buffer

See the below code for example. `size` is 1MB, and it certainly runs faster than when it is 1. I think it is due to that the number of IO system calls is reduced. Does this mean I will always benefit from a larger buffer size? I hoped so and ran some tests, but it seems that there is some limit. `size` being 2 will run much faster than when it is 1, but it doesn't go further that way.

Could someone explain this better? What is the optimal buffer size likely to be? And why don't I benefit much from expanding its size infinitely.

By the way, in this example I wrote to `stdout` for simplicity, but I'm also thinking about when writing to files in the disk.

```
enum
{
  size = 1 << 20
};

void fill_buffer(char (*)[size]);

int main(void)
{
  long n = 100000000;
  for (;;)
  {
    char buf[size];
    fill_buffer(&buf);
    if (n <= size)
    {
      if (fwrite(buf, 1, n, stdout) != n)
      {
        goto error;
      }
      break;
    }
    if (fwrite(buf, 1, size, stdout) != size)
    {
      goto error;
    }
    n -= size;
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
error:
  fprintf(stderr, "fwrite failed\n");
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: Optimal output buffer size is: 42.

Comment: This is so incredibly broad...

Comment: With a size of 1 you have a relatively high overhead by the syscalls involved. With a bigger size the percentage of the syscall-overhead goes down and the "real" writing into the filesystem cache takes up the runtime. I'd write the packages as big as possible.

Comment: There is no 'optimal'. It depends on the disk, the operating system, how much memory you can spare, ... There are diminishing returns as you increase. At some point the marginal value of the next increase is small enough that you don't want to pay for it. Test and measure.

Comment: On UNIX-like operating systems, you can find the optimal buffer size for a given file by calling `stat()` on it and looking at the `st_blksize()` member. If that's too tedious you can also use the `BUFSIZ` macro provided by `<stdio.h>` as a good default buffer size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You usually don't need the *best* buffer size, which may requires querying the OS for system parameters and do complex estimations or even benchmarking on the target environment, and it's dynamic. Lucky you just need a value that is *good enough*.

I would say a 4K~16K buffer suit most normal usages. Where 4K is the magic number for page size supported by normal machine (x86, arm) and also multiple of usual physical disk sector size(512B or 4K).

If you are dealing with huge amount of data (giga-bytes) you may realise simple fwrite-model is inadequate for its blocking nature.

Answer (score 1):

On a large partition, cluster size is often 32 KB. On a large read / write request, if the system sees that there are a series of contiguous clusters, it will combine them into a single I/O. Otherwise, it breaks up the request into multiple I/O's. I don't know what the maximum I/O size is. On some old SCSI controllers, it was 64 KB or 1 MB - 8 KB (17 or 255 descriptors, in controller). For IDE / Sata, I've been able to do IOCTL's for 2 MB, confirming it was a single I/O with an external bus monitor, but I never tested to determine the limit.

For external sorting with k way bottom up merge sort with k > 2, read / write size of 10 MB to 100 MB is used to reduce random access overhead. The request will be broken up into multiple I/O's but the read or write will be sequential (under ideal circumstances).